# How to calculate off shell decay channel's branch ratio

Tags: particle-physics

I know for the on shell decay, the branch ratio equal partial decay width divide by total decay width. But for off shell decay, for example , $H\to WW^*$, one of the $W$ is off shell, how to calculate the branch ratio of this channel?